# Count the value inside a value that is separated in comma, mysql

Tags: mysql

I have similar problem with him: Separately comma delimited column into unique column

```
 SELECT
    id, n.digit, name,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ',', n.digit+1), ',', -1)
 FROM
    mytable
 INNER JOIN
     (SELECT 0 digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3)  n
 ON LENGTH(REPLACE(name, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(name)-n.digit
```

Now, the answer worked... However, I have a different case. I have a database table

```
 ID     Transaction
 1      Chocolate, Milk
 2      Peanut, Beer, Chocolate
 3      Chocolate, Beer, Peanut
```

Now, I want it to look separate each item in comma like

```
 Chocolate 
 Milk  
 Peanut       
 Beer
```

and count how many times it is in the the table

```
 Order       Count
 Chocolate     3
 Milk          1
 Peanut        2
 Beer          2
```

Is there a way for that? in mYSQL form please

Comment: This will help you I guess https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/splitting-comma-separated-values-in-mysql

Comment: Thank you so much. That is a big help. However, there are some rows that somewhat duplicate. For example, instead of having Chocolate = 3, there are 2 rows, Chocolate = 1 and Chocolate = 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly go through the following URL

[https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/splitting-comma-separated-values-in-mysql here](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/splitting-comma-separated-values-in-mysql)

finally use the following query for avoiding space character if any

```
select items, count(1) from (
  select 
    id, 
    substring_index(
      substring_index(`transaction`, ',', n),
      ',', 
      -1
    ) as items
  from txn
  join numbers
    on char_length(`transaction`)
      - char_length(replace(`transaction`, ',', ''))
      >= n - 1
) email_recipients_by_dashboard
group by trim(items)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That is a big help. However, there are some rows that somewhat duplicate. For example, instead of having Chocolate = 3, there are 2 rows, Chocolate = 1 and Chocolate = 2

Comment: it is becuse of the space character infront of stripped string. use trim function in group by .

Answer (score 0):

You didn't get result as expected because there is some sort of space between the **commas**. So try like this. See demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7cddb3/1

**SCHEMA**

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  id INT,
  transaction VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO tablename VALUES
  (1, 'Chocolate, Milk'),
  (2, 'Peanut, Beer, Chocolate'),
  (3, 'Chocolate, Beer, Peanut');

CREATE TABLE numbers (
  n INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6);
```

**QUERY**

```
select transaction, count(1) from ( 
      select 
        id, 
        substring_index(
          substring_index(transaction, ',', n), 
          ',', 
          -1
        ) as transaction
      from tablename
      join numbers
        on char_length(transaction) 
          - char_length(replace(transaction, ',', '')) 
          >= n - 1
    ) tablename_numbers
    group by trim(transaction)
```

Comment: @Mamayg is that worked for you? Have you saw my edit with `trim()`